# Обычно(,) если я это делаю, то на это есть какая-то причина

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Обычно(,) если я это делаю, то на это есть какая-то причина.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужна, поскольку используется двойной союз ЕСЛИ..., ТО:

***Обычно если** я это делаю, **то** на это есть какая-то причина*.

Если бы второй части не было, придаточное бы обособлялось:

***Обычно, если** я это **делаю, на** это есть какая-то причина*.

Comment: А разве разрешено такое сочетание  для подчинительных союзов (ОБЫЧНО ЕСЛИ)? Вроде бы нет. Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку.

Comment: НЕТ ССЫЛКИ!  Ответ не соответствует ПРАВИЛАМ, а также ПРАКТИКЕ письма. Не обозначено влияние двойного  союза на выбор обособления. Почему в этом случае оно должно относиться к придаточному?

Answer (score 3):

Я выбираю обособление:

*ОбЫчно, / **если я это дЕлаю,** // то на это есть какая-то причИна.*

**Интонационное** выделение обстоятельства при обособлении.

**Пояснение**

1. При наличии **двойного** союза СПП рассматривается как единое целое.
2. Решение **нестандартное**, так как сочетание (наречие + подч. союз) не указано в правилах **как разрешенное.**
3. Обстоятельство со значением **обычности действия**, выраженное наречием,  можно обособить, так как оно **БЛИЖЕ** к тематике **вводных** слов (***как обычно, как правило***), чем присоединительные слова (***особенно, в частности*** и др.), которые указаны у **Розенталя**.
4. Сравнить:

***Как правило**, если я это делаю, то на это есть какая-то причина. **Обычно так**: если я это делаю, то на это есть какая-то причина.*

Здесь **ПОЛНОЗНАЧНОЕ**, а не **присоединительное** (как в правилах) значение наречия.

При наличии вводного слова: ***В самом деле, если** я это делаю, **то** на это есть какая-то причина.*

5. **Нацкорпус**  **ПРАКТИКА ПИСЬМА!**

***Обычно, если** кто-то садился за стол, дед не давал ему проглотить и куска без того, чтобы, угрюмо указывая глазами на тарелку едока, не процедить со значением: "Холестерин!* Марина Палей. Поминовение (1987)

***А обычно, если** мяч улетает за пределы поля, **то** за ним бегут, и часто борьба за него ведется чуть ли не у желтого дома.* С. И. Рыженков. Дворовые игры + // «Волга», 2013

**Вывод:** Наличие **ДВОЙНОГО СОЮЗА** не оказывает влияния на решение.

6. **ПРАВИЛО**

**[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)**

Пункт 5. Если перед подчинительным союзом стоят слова особенно, в частности, то есть, а именно, например, а также, а просто и т. п. **с присоединительным значением**, то запятая после этих слов не ставится.

У нас **нет присоединительного значения.**