# Ну ладно. Просто(,) если б кто-то был, он бы, возможно, мне помочь смог. Никто ей не нужен

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Ну ладно. Просто(,) если б кто-то был, он бы, возможно, мне помочь смог. Никто ей не нужен.

А здеся?

> Ну ладно. Просто(,) если б кто-то был, то он бы, возможно, мне помочь смог. Никто ей не нужен.

Comment: Повтор вопроса по этой  теме   https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476974/Обычно-если-я-это-делаю-то-на-это-есть-какая-то-причина   Вы намеренно повторяетесь или просто не помните, что уже спрашивали?

Comment: @Sharon Немного другой случай. В том вопросе было наречие, а здесь частица, она может примыкать и не к составному союзу.

Comment: А с каким значением? Это еще надо выбрать. https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=просто&mode=slovari&dicts[]=42